# Undestanding a detail about the colour bits in the ZGC algorithm

Tags: java, garbage-collection, zgc

I'm trying to understand how ZGC works in detail. Let's consider a simple Java example:

```
var v = new Object[]{ new Object() };
```

Let's call

- *a*: the array object
- *o*: the object referenced by *v[0]*
- *r*: the reference to *a*
- *s*: the reference to *o*

The image below shows the artefacts graphically: [image]

Let's assume that the first gc cycle starts and *a*, *o* are relocated. Let's further assume that the app doesn't access the objects.

> gc cycle 1:

a) Marking phase: at the end of the marking phase the *marked0* bit is set in *r*, *s*.

b) Relocation phase: At first, the root object *a* is relocated, *r* is remapped to the new location and the *remapped* bit of *r* is set. Then, *o* is relocated and the new location of *o* is written into the forwarding table.

*Note:* References originating in the heap aren't remapped in the relocation stage ([2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tShc0dyFtgw) at 9:20) - they are remapped in the next marking phase (or by the load barrier, if the app loads a reference before the next marking phase). Hence - to my understanding - the *marked0* bit is still set in *s*.

> gc cycle 2:

a) Marking phase:

a1) The *marked1* bit of *r* is set.

a2) Since the *remapped* bit of *s* is not set, gc looks into the forwarding table, sees the entry for *o*, remaps *s* to the new location of *o* and deletes the entry from the forwarding table.

**Question:** Which of the colour bits of *s* is now set?

*Consideration:* Since *s* has just been remapped, it would be natural to set the *remapped* bit. But gc is in the marking phase as well, so the *mapped1* bit has to be set.

**Why is this important:** If in step a2) the *marked* bit is set, this means that generally, after the marking phase has finished, all references originating in the heap have set a *marked* bit. So, whenever an app loads a reference from the heap for the first time after a marking phase finished, the load barrier has to check by accessing the forwarding table if the reference has been remapped.

This is (i) a performance burden, and (ii) unnecessary, because the gc knows from the remapping step (step a2) in the example) that the reference has been remapped. So, either the algorithm is not optimal, or the colour bits are set in a different way than described above.

Comment: I would appreciate if the downvoter would give a reason for the downvote. Of course, I would also appreciate an answer.

Comment: “the mapped0 bit is still set in s” makes no sense, as it wasn’t set before and hasn’t set unless remapping took place. But your point was that it didn’t take place for s, hence, the mapped bit is still unset.

Comment: @Holger: Yes, thanks, that is a typo. Fixed.

Comment: So “mapped1” is also supposed to be “marked1”. But the gc will use the “marked2” bit when the previous gc cycle used the “marked1” bit.